# Squid ecap_adapter_gzip problem

Tags: linux, proxy, squid

I have a problem with ecap gzip adapter for squid. 
I installed squid 3.1.10, libecap 0.0.3 and squid-ecap-gzip.

For squid I used cofiguration:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/squid --enable-ecap --enable-icap --enable-icap-client  --enable-icap-support --g
```

and I installed adapter following install procedures.
When I start squid in cache.log i can see that it can not load services from:

```
ecap://www.vigos.com/ecapal/lib/ecap_adapt_gzip
```

If any one knows what could have gone wrong, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create shared object '.so' file of your adapter and specify it in squid config using using

```
ecap_enable on
loadable_modules <path to .so file>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load your object like this at the `/usr/local/squid/etc/squid.conf`

```
ecap_enable on

loadable_modules /usr/local/lib/ecap_adapter_modifying.so

ecap_service ecapModifier respmod_precache uri=ecap://e-cap.org/ecap/services/sample/modifying 

adaptation_access ecapModifier allow all
```